# Access a function of view.py in from.py

Tags: django, django-forms, django-views

How do I access a result of a view.py function inside form.py?

I am trying to use the results of a function of view as input of a form field

Here is my code

Views.py

```
def inc(request):
    user_name = request.user.username
    u = User.objects.get(username=user_name)
    cont = u.accesslevel.numb
```

Admin.py

```
class AccessLevelInline(admin.StackedInline):
    model = AccessLevel
    can_delete = False
    verbose_name_plural = 'accesslevel'

# Define a new User admin
class UserAdmin(BaseUserAdmin):
    inlines = (AccessLevelInline, )

# Re-register UserAdmin
admin.site.unregister(User)
admin.site.register(User, UserAdmin)
```

Form.py

```
user_name = HOW DO I ACCESS THE USER NAME FROM VIEWS HERE?
u = User.objects.get(username=user_name).accesslevel.prod.split(',')
v=(('---------','---------'),)
for l in u:
v=v+((l.lstrip(),l.lstrip()),)

class ProductForm(forms.Form):
    model = ManufactForm    
    Prod = forms. ChoiceField(choices=v)
```

Comment: Please show your code or code structure.

Comment: sure.. code inserted in the question

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your python files are `Form.py` and `View.py`,
at the top of the `Form.py`, import your `View.py` like this.

```
import View
```

Then you can call any function from your `view.py` file,

```
View.inc()
```

Comment: I am having the following erro msg: ImportError: No module named view

Comment: Are all the files in the same directory? and make sure the file name is correct. If your file is `View.py` then the import line should be `import View`

Comment: sorry it was views... but now AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute inc

Comment: what is the function you want to import from "views"?

Comment: inc.. I am doing the following views.inc().. and the erro msg is AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'inc'

Comment: It should be working. Are you inside a python module or something? Check this https://i.imgur.com/fUBVoym.png . This is my two files and the file structure.